# Local var available in global scope?

Tags: python

In this code snippet I forgot to define the variable `content` in the outer scope. Then I assign a value to `content` in the `with` block. After leaving the `with` block the value of the variable `content` still exists. Why?

```
data_dir = "/Users/ugur/code/automating_tools/calibre"
kindle_drm_csv = "amazon_drm_books.csv"
csv_path = f"{data_dir}/{kindle_drm_csv}"


# I forgot to define this:
# content = ""
with open(csv_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    # read whole content
    content = csv_file.read()

# why could I still print the content of the var?
# shouldn't it be undefined after leaving the `with` block?
print(content)
```

Also in this example:

```
if 3<10:
    local_var = True
print(local_var) 
# prints True
# why?
# I left the if-then-block. 
# Shouldn't the local_var be undefined after leaving the block?
```

Comment: @Philipp Excellent. Thanks. But still: My second example cannot be explained with your link.

Comment: The first line of the accepted answer in the thread I sent states that with, if, for and while do not create a scope in Python. Does that explain your question in the second example?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python in not C. C automatic variables are indeed block scoped, but Python variables are either global or function scoped (*). As you are at the same function level, the variable declared in the block still exists after the end of the block.

---

(*) a corner case is that comprehensions are handled as *hidden* function. So a variable declared in a comprehension will hide any higher level scope variables of same name, and will vanish outside of the comprehension

Answer (score 1):

There is no local scope (block scope) in python, only function and global scope.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `with` and `if` do not create their own scope. In the code you have provided, `content` and `local_var` are created in the global scope and are thus accessible outside of the `with` and `if` statements. The only Python constructs that create their own scope are modules, classes, functions, generator expressions, and dict/set/list comprehensions.

Comment: So is it not a good practice to define a variable prior to using it in an `if` block or `with` block?